# ReferenceError when Javascript function is inserted via innerHTML

Tags: php, javascript, smarty, innerhtml

I have a problem calling a Javascript function that was inserted into a `<div>` via the innerHTML property. I have searched through similar threads in SO, but I wasn't able to find a solution to this problem.

In a simplified version, here is what I have:

### **MainPage.php**

```
// ... Basic Headers 
<div id = 'list'>
    {include file="list.tpl"}
</div>
// More stuff...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callbackFunction(data) {
        $('list').innerHTML = data.updatedListHTML;
        updateCalculatedFields();
    }
    // Perform a Ajax POST Request with the callbackFunction()
</script>
```

### **List.tpl**

```
{if $thereIsData}
    // Create a table, populate its content...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateCalculatedFields() {
             // Change some of the values in the created table...
        }
    </script>
{/if}
```

With the code above, I get a ReferenceError in the `callbackFunction(data)` while trying to call the `updateCalculatedFields()` function. I have double-checked to see that the innerHTML has been properly updated;, the `updateCalculatedFields()` function (and the whole script tag) has been added to the div. However, Javascript cannot seem to find injected function.

With a small change, the functionality works. If the list.tpl were to be changed to:

### **List.tpl (version 2)**

```
{if $thereIsData}
    // Create a table, populate its content...
{/if}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateCalculatedFields() {
         // Change some of the values in the created table...
    }
</script>
```

The different between the two scenarios is that in the second one, the `updateCalculatedFields()` function is loaded with the page right from the start. In the first one, it gets added later with the innerHTML. So, my conclusion is that Javascript will not register functions that get added via innerHTML. I highly doubt that this is the case though; so it would be great if someone could give an explanation on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is not evaluated when inserted with innerHTML. You either need to eval() it yourself or append a new external script tag to the page.

Comment: I have read that the JavaScript wasn't evaluated when inserted with innerHTML. However, I have interpreted as Javascript code not being executed. In other words, the function wasn't run. However, from your answer, I understand that eval() basically interprets the code as Javascript; as a result, making the inserted function ready to be run. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case (to answer my own question).